# auto restart Apache when high load average

Tags: shell-script, cron, apache-httpd

My server always shut down when it reach a high load average. I have optimized my Apache, MySQL. But I cannot prevent sometime in a heavy traffic. So I try to write some shell to control load average.

```
#!/bin/bash
check=`uptime | sed 's/\./ /' | awk '{print $10}'`
if[$check -gt 5]
then
  /usr/bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
fi
```

but it report error when I excuse the script

```
/var/www/html/load_average.sh: line 3: if[0.98, -gt 5]: command not found
/var/www/html/load_average.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
/var/www/html/load_average.sh: line 4: `then'
```

Another question, how to run the script in every 10 seconds with cronjob?

another working code, share to everyone:

```
#!/bin/bash
check=$(uptime | tr -d ',' | awk '{print $10}')
if [[ $check > 5 ]]; then
  /usr/bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
fi
```

in cronjob part

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/load_average.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 10; /var/www/html/load_average.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 20; /var/www/html/load_average.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 30; /var/www/html/load_average.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 40; /var/www/html/load_average.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 50; /var/www/html/load_average.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Rather than auto-restart Apache httpd, it's infinitely preferable to limit/throttle the application so as to not overwhelm the system (perhaps you've done this, still without the desired results; but it's still worth spending time on. Automatically restarting the server may exacerbate your existing issues.) See either standard httpd conf options and/or modules to help keep the servers & system at optimal performance:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/  , http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/perf-tuning.html , http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1495/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must separate the brackets from the data with spaces, like this:

```
for I in 0 1 2 3 4 5; do
    check=$(uptime | tr -d ',.' | awk '{print $10}')
    if [ "$check" -gt 5 ]; then
        /usr/bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
    fi
    sleep 10
done
```

In UNIX, [ is really [a shell command](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=test). When the shell replaces the $check variable by its value, it will try to find the resulted command, hence the error. Additionally, I suggest you quoting the $check variable, as if it gets replaced by an empty string or a whitespace, it would by a syntax error.

Regarding your crontab question, execute **crontab -e** and add an entry like this one to your file:

```
* * * * * /PATH/TO/YOUR/SCRIPT
```

Cronjobs minimal resolution elapse time is 1 minute, so, you will have to use a loop for repeting the check 6 times every ten seconds.

Comment: still report error `/var/www/html/load_average.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token then'` `/var/www/html/load_average.sh: line 4: if[$check -gt 1]; then'`. I have edit it in ssh vi commond.

Comment: White spaces around the brackets are compulsory. You must separate the [ from the if and the $check tokens. The same for the compared value. `if [ "$check" -gt 1 ]`

Comment: now only report `/var/www/html/load_average.sh: line 3: if[0.93, -gt 5]: command not found`, why there has a common before ` -gt`?

Comment: Data is still not separated from the brackets with spaces.

Comment: I have added brackets with spaces.

Comment: The comma is due to the way $check value is set. Look at my answer for an alternative way to avoid this.

Comment: #uptime, load average: 0.73, 0.40, 1.15, how to prevent the last value 1.15, 15 minutes value do not over 2 in bash?

Comment: As uptime load average values have two decimals, easiest trick here is comparing it to 200. Another option would be taking only the integer part.

Answer (score 0):

> `if[0.98, -gt 5]`

Bash can't do floating point arithmetic. You can do `if (( 98 > 500 ))` - double round parens allow arithmetic expressions and variable expanding is done in such automatically, so  `if (( check > 500 ))` if your variable is `$check`. Fortunately, awk does handle basic arithmetic pretty well.

```
#!/bin/bash
check=$(LC_ALL=C uptime | awk '{print 100*$10 }')
if (( check > 5 ))
then
  /usr/bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
fi
```

Backticks are deprecated for ages, now.

However, restarting the web server, when too busy might annoy enough visitors, to push the load average down. It doesn't lock as the right solution since it increases the work. Maybe a profiler might help in finding a bottleneck.

And probably better ways to limit the load average, the web server may cause, exist from within the project - I could only give advice how to improve the shell script.

The LC_ALL setting is probably only needed on my machine, which uses a German environment by default and shows 0.83 as 0,83. But it will not be wrong either.